# Cache Control on wwwroot subfolders Net core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, webpack, .net-core, cache-control

I'm trying to add cache control headers to .js and .css files which live in wwwroot/dist. If I output my files directly into wwwroot rather than wwwroot/dist (from webpack) the headers are added without issue via the below code:

```
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
                {
                    const int durationInSeconds = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365;
                    ctx.Context.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] =
                        "public,max-age=" + durationInSeconds;
                }
        });
```

however this method seems to ignore sub folders.
Due to this I have added the following code directly below the code seen above:

```
         app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "dist")),
            RequestPath = "/dist",
            OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
            {
                const int durationInSeconds = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365;

                    ctx.Context.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] =
                        "public,max-age=" + durationInSeconds;  
            }
        });
```

The files do ideally need to be contained in the 'dist' folder as this is ignored in source control and the output files contain a hash so I can't feasibly manually add them to my git ignore.

Further to this it seems like any files served from a sub folder of wwwroot always have no-cache set in the request headers.

Any advice on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve it?
I had the same problem using `UseWebpackDevMiddleware` for Webpack, and it seems that the middleware branched the request for the static files bundled by webpack.

Temporary remove the middleware config made the `UseStaticFiles` work as expected.

In production the middleware is not used and work as is.